# How can i embed a pygal chart in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygal

i am working with pygal currently, and i want to embed pygal's chart in a tkinter gui is it possible?.
code i found for the pygal chart:

```
line_chart = pygal.Line()
line_chart.title = 'Browser usage evolution (in %)'
line_chart.x_labels = map(str, range(2002, 2013))
line_chart.add('Firefox', [None, None,    0, 16.6,   25,   31, 36.4, 45.5, 46.3, 42.8, 37.1])
line_chart.add('Chrome',  [None, None, None, None, None, None,    0,  3.9, 10.8, 23.8, 35.3])
line_chart.add('IE',      [85.8, 84.6, 84.7, 74.5,   66, 58.6, 54.7, 44.8, 36.2, 26.6, 20.1])
line_chart.add('Others',  [14.2, 15.4, 15.3,  8.9,    9, 10.4,  8.9,  5.8,  6.7,  6.8,  7.5])
line_chart.render()
```

Comment: You can use `render_to_png("test.png")` (need `cairosvg` module) and show the image using tkinter.